# How do I remove the glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar that NetBeans automatically adds for unit testing?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, glassfish

I'm developing a Java JPA JAX-RS app using NetBeans 7.1.1 and GlassFish 3.1.2, and I'm stuck creating unit tests for my Web Application. I believe the problem is that the glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar that NetBeans adds to the project's Test Libraries UI folder is conflicting with the one I want (glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.jar), which I added manually. I tried different ways of deleting it, but it is apparently special - there is no Remove or Delete option available in the UI. I see that it's mentioned in my project.properties file:

```
j2ee.platform.embeddableejb.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/lib/embedded/glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar
```

So I tried closing the project, editing out that line, and re-opening the project, but it always returns from the grave. I tried looking for it in the project's properties under Libraries > Compile Tests, but it doesn't show up there. Maybe you've found a way to remove similar special files from your NetBeans project? Thank you -- matt

Comment: dude, where did you download glassfish-embedded-static-shell-3.1.2.jar the one I managed to download is only 7k and has POM references but no actual classes.

Comment: Yea, it was kind of an SOB to find: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.2/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.jar . Confusingly, the previous version was located here: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.1/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.1.jar

Comment: Download? According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2424/gjlde.html), you'll already have this file in your glassfish installation directory: "as-install/glassfish/lib/embedded" ("as-install" is most likely "C:\glassfish3" on a Windows machine). You're even asked to reference the file from this directory and not move it. Although I'm having trouble getting this stuff to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was to dump NetBeans and switch (back) to IntelliJ IDEA, which has much more flexible project configuration options. I created separate run configurations for testing and deployment using their module feature:
[image: test module config]
[image: main module config]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Close the project from within Neatbeans. Close Netbeans, then.
Locate from the file `../yourProject/nbproject/project.xml`
Remove the following line (almost at the bottom):

```
<root id="test.src.dir"/>
```

Open the project again.